# Notepad ++ : Regular expression to join multiple lines in single line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to join lines to make questions (having serial no. in order 1,2,3....) in one line and all options as shown below in another single line ? Example :
 
1.For his alleged
 
 involvements in
espio-nage
(1) abc
(2) saf
(3) asf
(4) aqg

Output should be:
  1. For his alleged involvement in espio-nage...
   (1)abc (2)saf (3)asf (4)aqg

Note:I just want to make it compact to read in kindle reader so that maximum space will get utilised

Comment: Input : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdefgvcusnaszsp/Input.txt?dl=0
Output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlhydvph7ufkoyj/Output.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I think

\r?\n(?!\(1|\d)

(And replace with empty string) will do what you want

Explanation: Looks for a newline that's not followed by either (1 or a single digit.

If you ever have more than 9 options that will cause problems as it'll split before (10 (11 etc. - in which case \r?\n(?!\(1\)|\d) should do it

Comment: Thanks it worked . Before joining how can it add space before ? Please help .

Comment: A space before what?

Answer (score 0):

Select text/elements and press CTRL+J

Comment: Or go to:
Edit > Line Operations > Join Lines

Comment: there are 100s of similar question in single text file. If i do so all of them join in single line and i will not be able to read them so distinctly.

Comment: Ctrl+J just join all lines in single one so I don't know whay u need to join all lines in single one but that is the command. I prefer multiple lines to understand better what is happen there.